# Get max value from points based on distinct id, and keep geometry for the new selection

Tags: postgis, postgresql, select

I have a pointfile of approx.. 226000 points, where I need to filter by max value and distinct id_pol.

```sql
SELECT  distinct (id_pol), MAX(value)
FROM    fillspill_pol_value
GROUP BY id_pol;
```

This expression gives me 460 rows, which is correct, but when I add geometry to the selection, it gives me 226000 rows. How can I select only the geometry for the 460 points (the max values)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `d_pol` is not unique across `geom`, and thus you want to *select the [row with the] `geom` having the maximum `value` within each `id_pol` group*, you need to select them from a ranked sub-query:

```
SELECT id_pol,
       "value",
       geom
FROM   (
  SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id_pol ORDER BY "value" DESC) AS _rank
  FROM   fillspill_pol_value
) q
WHERE  _rank = 1
;
```

`ROW_NUMBER` assigns a `_rank` in descending order of `"value"` per group (*window*) of `id_pol`; see [*Window Functions*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to join the geometries to the selected values:

```
SELECT distinct (a.id_pol), MAX(a.value), b.geometry
FROM fillspill_pol_value a GROUP BY id_pol
LEFT JOIN fillspill_pol_value b ON a.id_pol, b.id_pol;
```

Since we are joining the table `fillspill_pol_value` to itself, we must distinguish the left and right table by giving it names (e.g. `a` and `b` in my example).

Comment: thanks for your sugestion, Stefan. But I get an error:; ERROR:  syntax error at or near "LEFT" LINE 3: LEFT INNER JOIN fillspill_pol_value b ON a.id_pol, b.id_pol;

And could you please explain why you have added the b into the expression?

Comment: My bad, according to [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-select.html), there is no `LEFT INNER JOIN`. :D I have updated my answer.

`a` and `b` are needed to distinguish the left table from the right one since we are effectively joining the table to itself.